# Worldserver changing ports after docker-compose down & docker-compose up

Tags: docker, docker-compose, azerothcore

I'm using [AzerothCore with Docker](https://www.azerothcore.org/wiki/Install-with-Docker).

I've noticed that after running `docker-compose down` and `docker-compose up` my `worldserver` and the database now uses different ports than the defaults. How to prevent this?

Note: the `authserver` port remained the same.

I use Windows 10 20H2 (Build 19042.844)

Comment: Docker-compose file in their github repo uses environment variables for ports. Could you please provide values of next variables `DB_EXTERNAL_PORT`, `WORLD_EXTERNAL_PORT`, `SOAP_EXTERNAL_PORT`?

Comment: I'm sorry, I've looked but I don't know where to insert those commands, I'm just starting to learn and I'm quite lost

Answer (score 0):

Normally docker creates automatically a tunnel on a random free port for any service that tries to bound on its own network.
However, unless you changed the **WORLD_EXTERNAL_PORT** or the port is already busy for some reason, the original port (together with the random one) should be open as well.

you can run the `docker-compose ps` or the `docker ps` to check which are network ports open.

Also, this behaviour changes based on your OS. Can you specify it in your first post, please?

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the prompt reply, I haven't changed anything about WORLD_EXTERNAL_PORT, as for 'docker-compose ps' again my overwhelming inexperience comes out hehe, dont know where to enter the command, the 'docker ps' gives this result:
[image]

Comment: From the screenshot, you provided I can see that the ports are correctly open using the default values.

Comment: So I shouldn't worry and I deduce that it is normal behavior, right? even though those new random ports have been added and used after the docker-compose down and up

Comment: if the original port still works, you should not worry about it

Comment: okey, i will keep an eye on it, thanks again and take care :)

Comment: hey @Eldarix welcome to StackOverflow ;) just a small note: you posted an answer here but it should be actually a comment on Joseph's answer.

Comment: :) don't know how to reestructure it now, again sorry, i try to read all and be adjusted to the methods and structures the best i can. 

Health and Strenght and have a nice day !

Comment: @FrancescoBorzi Eldarix also had to share a screenshot, comments do not support attachments here as far as I know. Maybe next time the forum would be better or maybe update the first post instead

Comment: @Eldarix can you vote my answer if it has been useful for you?

Comment: It seems that I do not have the necessary permissions to vote yet, but without a doubt it was useful, I thank you, as for the answers and their order, I will try to put it better next time, certainly when trying to correct it, it would not let me put the image.

Greetings.